# Convert float to int and limit it to -1 <-> 1

Tags: c, integer

Sounds simple but I need a way to limit an int to this range only without overflow.
Or to limit it to 0 - 1
For all possible float input values.  Without a comparison.

Limiting the float is also acceptable, but it needs to be fast.

UPDATE:  Have found the solution for range 0 - 1

```
int i = (int)f;
i = (((i + (i-1))%2)+1)/2;
```

No need to downvote a poorly phrased question.
No idea how it will function near the top half of the range.

Comment: `float f; int i; ... i = (int)f; if(i < -1 || i > 1) printf("Error");`

Comment: Or "we have no idea what you want"

Comment: why the bit-manipulation tag?

Comment: The post is not clear if the values between 0.0 and 1.0 are to become 0, 1 or either.

Answer (score 4):

This limits the values to 0-1

```
float f;
int i = (f>=1);
```

If you want a result from the set {-1,0,1} try

```
float f;
int i = (f>=1)-(f<=1);
```

you can switch to other thresholds if you want to do some sort of rounding

Comment: Without compare statements

Comment: why without compares? compares are cheap, this is branch free

Comment: If you don't want compare, you will need this one: `i=((-!!((*(int*)&(f))&(-1UL>>1)))&(-((*(int*)&(f))>>(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1))))|(!!(*(int*)&(f))&(-1UL>>1))`

Comment: I would guess because it is 1 or more of A) homework b) a past-paper or c) an interview question

Comment: well i can say that we do this all the time at work, and its way way faster than extracting the sign bit or doing other nonsense

Comment: Does that mean there is perfect prediction?

Comment: no, that means there is no branch at all here. no jump, no nothing, it translates to a single line of assembly (if you have mmx)

Comment: Will try it out and report back

Comment: Compare is the fastest approach. Compare is not equal to branch.

Comment: But can it risk breaking pipeline?